# Generic GetTable from datacontext

Tags: vb.net, linq, generics

I'm looking for a way to create a generic function/property to get the table from my datacontext.
Now i have several properties that each call the GetTable function, but i would like to join them in one generic function.

```
Partial Public Class SAdminDataContext
Inherits DataContext    
Public ReadOnly Property GetCustomer() As Table(Of Customer)
    Get
        Try
            Return GetTable(Of Customer)()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Get
End Property
'...

Public ReadOnly Property GetCustomerPerson() As Table(Of CustomerPerson)
    Get
        Try
            Return GetTable(Of CustomerPerson)()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Get
End Property End Class
```

and then i get the data like this:

```
dim datasource = dataContext.GetCustomer
```

Comment: What about the GetTable(Of T) method?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap in another layer of generics

```
Public Function GetIt(Of T)() As List(Of T)
    Dim it As New List(Of T)

    Return it

End Function
```

And to call it:

```
Dim l = GetIt(Of String)()
```

The same concept should work for the above approach.